How do I configure an IDE for pyROOT?
I am new to ROOT and looking to use pyROOT in particular. I want to setup pyROOT for an IDE and the few resources I found online did not seem to present how to configure an IDE and worked straight with the terminal or a txt file opened from the terminal. I tried setting up pyROOT on my Ubuntu machine through the Spyder IDE, but ran into many errors. I was wondering if there exists some recommended setup?

I don't know pyROOT but I don't understand what so special you want to do with this module in IDE. If it is normal python module then you need to install in Python (e.g. using pip) and later you can use it in code in any IDE. And if you need to do something different then you have to describe it in question (not in comments) with details. What means straight with the terminal or a txt file opened from the terminal.? If you want to run script in terminal and get filename as argument then use sys.argv to get this filename in code. But this doesn't need any changes in IDE.

If you found some resources then you could show links in question (not in comments)
